# Merging different columns of different tables in one select query in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables:
Table: AA with columns A, B , C, D
Table: BB with columns E , F G

I want to get output which is  a combination of these two tables like following:

```
A | B | C | D | E | F | G
```

I am currently doing following:

```
Select * from ( 

( select A, B, C ,D from AA where some condition)

UNION ALL

( select E , F , G , NULL from BB where some condition) )
```

But it is giving me output which contains only A , B , C , D from AA table while it's not adding E, F , G from table BB.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you want them side by side you need to join them. The ubiob query *is* adding the data from BB (if condition is true) - but it's concatenating it at the end of the AA data.

Comment: Do those tables have fields in common?  In other words, are A and E essentially the same type of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure exactly what you idea is , but if you want just plain data from AA and BB in same table display then you can use something like this

```
 ( select A, B, C ,D, NULL as E, NULL as F, NULL as G from AA where some condition)

 UNION ALL

( select NULL as A , NULL as B, NULL as C, NULL as D, E , F , G  from BB where some condition) )
```

but not sure what is the point of this :|

if you want some combination of data then join is must have.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for results that look something like this:

```
A1  B1  C1  D1 
A2  B2  C2  D2 
A3  B3  C3  D3 
E1  F1  G1 
E2  F2  G2
```

then try something like

```
(select A Fld1, B Fld2, C Fld3, D Fld4 from AA where some condition)
union
(select E Fld2, F Fld2, G Fld3, Null from BB where some condition)
```

In other words, give a common alias for the fields that are the same between the two selects.  And of course, the fields must be the same types.